# React setState on array resets value to null right after call (Functional component)

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Sorry to ask this question but after a long day of research I still can't understand why but when I'm calling setState on my array, value comes back to null right after. 
My code worked and then I had to turn my component into a functional component to use MaterialUI and it stopped working. I tried using useEffect, the value in the hook is good, but right after it comes back to the initial value.

(variable in question is markers, and it always comes back to [null, null])

Is it because I'm storing an object maybe ?

code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

import './app.css'
import Map from './Map'
import PlaceSearch from './PlaceSearch'
import { useReducer } from 'react';

function NewTrip () {
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([50.631290, 3.062750])
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([null, null])
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(13)

  // const initialState = {markers: [null, null]}
  // const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  // Load leaflet icons for markers
  const redIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png',
    shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowSize: [41, 41]
  });
  const blueIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-blue.png',
    shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowSize: [41, 41]
  }); 

  useEffect(() => {
    debugger
  })

  const departChanged = (e) => {
    var selectedPoint = e.suggestion.latlng
    var newMarkers = {...markers}

    newMarkers[0] = new L.marker(selectedPoint, {icon: blueIcon})
    setMapCenter([selectedPoint.lat, selectedPoint.lng])
    setMarkers(newMarkers)
    //dispatch({type: 'set_markers', payload: newMarkers})
    debugger
  }

  const arrivalChanged = (e) => {
    var selectedPoint = e.suggestion.latlng
    var newMarkers = {...markers}

    newMarkers[1] = new L.marker(selectedPoint, {icon: redIcon})
    setMapCenter([selectedPoint.lat, selectedPoint.lng])
    setMarkers(newMarkers)
  }

  //const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-centered">Nouveau trajet</h1>
      <br/>
      <div className="split left">
        <div className="center">
          <PlaceSearch suggestionChanged={departChanged} placeholder={"Départ"} inputId={"departSearch"}></PlaceSearch>
          <PlaceSearch suggestionChanged={arrivalChanged} placeholder={"Arrivée"} inputId={"arrivalSearch"}></PlaceSearch>
          {/* <Map center={mapCenter} markers={markers} zoom={zoom}></Map> */}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="split right">
        <div className="center">
          <h2>Places disponibles</h2>
          <input id="seats" type="number" max="9" min="1" defaultValue="2"/>
          <p>(Min 1, Max 9)</p>
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewTrip;
```

As you can see I even tried using reducer instead of state but result was the same.

=====   UPDATE  =====

Ok after some research, the value is correctly set but the value is different when accessed from inside the dapartChanged and arrivalChanged functions or outside of it. Outside of the function the value is normal, inside the value is always Array [null, null]

Comment: What do you mean by "comes back to?" We have no context for at what point is it correctly set or reset.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being unclear.

Actually, right after the setMarkers call, the value gets resetted, I checked if the values are updated using a hook and they are, but the values are reset right after that.
My guess is it's resetted because the method is called from a child component maybe, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: No, tried calling a method from my parent component and problem was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that I was calling the departChanged and arrivalChanged methods from a child component, and apparently in that context all values I accessed were default state values.

I don't know how to fix it but for now I replaced it with useRef and it works.

If anybody has a clue on why the state values are default when the function is called by another component, please drop a comment ^^

Answer (score 0):

To change a specific element in an existing array with `setMarkers` you can do

```
const departChanged = (e) => {
  var selectedPoint = e.suggestion.latlng
  setMapCenter([selectedPoint.lat, selectedPoint.lng])
  setMarkers((prev) => [new L.marker(selectedPoint, {icon: blueIcon}), prev[1]])
}

const arrivalChanged = (e) => {
  var selectedPoint = e.suggestion.latlng
  setMapCenter([selectedPoint.lat, selectedPoint.lng])
  setMarkers((prev) => [prev[0], new L.marker(selectedPoint, {icon: redIcon})])
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but I tried that too and had no luck either.. someone told me that' it may be that my component gets remounted, any ideas on that maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

You're spreading the markers in to an object but then calling it like you would an array.

```js
const arrivalChanged = (e) => {
    var selectedPoint = e.suggestion.latlng
    var newMarkers = {...markers} /*<==== should probably be const newMarkers = [...markers];*/

    newMarkers[1] = new L.marker(selectedPoint, {icon: redIcon})
    setMapCenter([selectedPoint.lat, selectedPoint.lng])
    setMarkers(newMarkers)
  }
```

If this still fails, please `console.log(newMarkers)` prior to using `setMarkers` so we can see what the data looks like.